# Fetch Custom collection into the view, what is the right way ( magento way)?

Tags: module, blocks, view

```
$collection=Mage::getModel('todaywerecommend/todaywerecommend')->getCollection()
            ->addfieldtofilter('fromdate',
                array(
                    array('to' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate())))
            ->addfieldtofilter('todate',
                array(
                    array('gteq' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate()))
            );
        $collection->setOrder('id','DESC')->setPageSize(1);
```

I am fetching my Featured product using the above collection.

Where should this snippet should be ? Should it be in models then  call in block and set value for my view or can  do this in block a  then set value for the view ? what is the right way?

I used to use it in my view file , and that not right .

Edit
Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <todaywerecommend>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend</module>
            <frontName>todaywerecommend</frontName>
          </args>
      </todaywerecommend>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <todaywerecommend>
              <file>todaywerecommend.xml</file>
            </todaywerecommend>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <todaywerecommend>
        <class>Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend_Helper</class>
      </todaywerecommend>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <todaywerecommend>
        <class>Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend_Block</class>
      </todaywerecommend>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <todaywerecommend>
        <class>Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>todaywerecommend_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </todaywerecommend>
      <todaywerecommend_mysql4>
        <class>Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>        
              <todaywerecommend>
                <table>todaywerecommend</table>
              </todaywerecommend>
        </entities>
      </todaywerecommend_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <todaywerecommend_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </todaywerecommend_setup>
      <todaywerecommend_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </todaywerecommend_write>
      <todaywerecommend_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </todaywerecommend_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <todaywerecommend>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend</module>
          <frontName>admin_todaywerecommend</frontName>
        </args>
      </todaywerecommend>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <todaywerecommend module="todaywerecommend">
        <title>TodayWeRecommend</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <todaywerecommend module="todaywerecommend">
            <title>Manage Todaywerecommend</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_todaywerecommend/adminhtml_todaywerecommend</action>
          </todaywerecommend>
        </children>
      </todaywerecommend>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <todaywerecommend translate="title" module="todaywerecommend">
              <title>TodayWeRecommend</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <todaywerecommend translate="title">
            <title>Manage Todaywerecommend</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
          </todaywerecommend>
              </children>
            </todaywerecommend>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <todaywerecommend>
          <file>todaywerecommend.xml</file>
        </todaywerecommend>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Model

```
<?php

class Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend_Model_Todaywerecommend extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct(){

       $this->_init("todaywerecommend/todaywerecommend");

    }

}
```

Comment: Change u please share code of config..xml & mode

Comment: @AmitBera Done!

Comment: todaywerecommend table columns details.

Comment: @AmitBera script :- create table todaywerecommend(id int not null auto_increment, sku varchar(225), fromdate DATETIME(6),todate DATETIME(6),  primary key(id));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To get the right way, you need to look into core Magento.

Your case is similar to normal product list page. The most important template which is resposible to show product list is `catalog/product/list.phtml`. Basically this is what you can see in that file.

```
<?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection(); ?>
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product) : ?>
    <?php //code to list product goes here ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The class stands for this template is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and you can find `getLoadedProductCollection()` in that class. Since product list page is pretty complex stuff, you cannot see a direct collection load there. But normally you can find lot of examples like this in such block classes.

```
public function getSomeCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('some_model/someentity')->getCollection();
    return $collection;
}
```

or

```
public function getSomeCollection()
{
    return Mage::getModel('some_model/someentity')->getMyCollection();
}
```

and then real collection is defined inside the model class.

So in my opinion, you can follow either of these conventions. I normally prefer :

1. **If the collection is not complex** - Define a template file and call a collection method there. Then define the collection method in the corresponding block class that will load "real collection" directly.
2. **If the collection is complex** - Define a template file and call a collection method there. Then define that collection method in the corresponding block class that will call a model class which will actually do the "real collection".

Hope you got the idea

Comment: It helped me a lot thanks , was looking for this for a long time , one more question ... is this right way to include that phtml in a static block where i fetched the custom collection      {{block type="todaywerecommend/index" name="todaywerecommend_index" template="todaywerecommend/index.phtml"}}

Answer (score 1):

### Define resource Model & resource Collection

As *you want to get Collection* then you must define  ***`resource Model & resource Collection model`*** Which is ***`interact Magento with Database`***.

**First define resource Model:**

```
<?php
/*
@Author Amit Bera
@Email dev.amitbera@gmail.com
@ Website: www.amitbera.com
*/
class Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend_Model_Resource_Todaywerecommend extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract{

    protected function _construct(){
        $this->_init('todaywerecommend/todaywerecommend','id');
    }


}
```

**then Resource Collection model**

```
<?php
/*
@Author Amit Bera
@Email dev.amitbera@gmail.com
@ Website: www.amitbera.com
*/
class Vishwas_TodayWeRecommend_Model_Resource_Todaywerecommend_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{
    protected function _construct(){
        $this->_init('todaywerecommend/todaywerecommend');
    }
}
```

### Populate Collection with magento product Collection

For **getting feature collection** `$collection` is ***right code but from $collection,it
does not give you full Product Collection*** like Magento  product Collection
`Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')`  or
`Mage::getModel('catalog/product_collection')->getCollection()`; do

because of ***$collection***  maximum give sku list  using  *getColumnValues()*

`$collection->getColumnValues('sku');`

My suggestion,**It will better to create Product Collection using magento product collection**

then filter that **Collection by list of sku which you have get from $collection**.

```
$proudctCollection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttribute('sku','in'=>$collection->getColumnValues('sku'));

/* You can add below as per your wish */

$proudctCollection
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addUrlRewrite();
```

Comment: ok But how where do i filter  my collection and fetch in view , Sorry for such question but i m trying to do what should be magento way not the easy way around so eger to learn the right way